# How to limit input from textbox to numbers 0-9?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have this text input field in the following example, which is set to only accept numbers:

```
<input type="number">
```

Live example over here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cL1ptdLv/1/

The problem is that I am able to enter "e", comma, dot etc. But in my GUI I need to restrict input to be only numbers 0-9 (integers) like 235 and not 2e35. How can I do that?

**Solution:**

Here is the solution based on answer from suprabhat

In JQuery:

```
$(".onlyNumber").keypress(function (evt) {
    if (!(evt.keyCode >= 48 && evt.keyCode <= 57))
        evt.preventDefault();
});
```

and in html I added the new class called onlyNumber to my inputbox:

```
<input type=number class="onlyNumber">
```

Comment: You can do it in JS or in the .NET - Is the input being rendered from .NET?

Comment: [JsFiddle Limit Number](https://jsfiddle.net/cL1ptdLv/2/).

Comment: Yes I do that from .NET.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have used for the textbox is right.

You can use the below Javascript code for validation.

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And call it in your textbox

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specified three event handlers, `onkeypress`, `ondrop` and `onpaste` for the textbox.

On the `onkeypress` event handler, I am making call to a JavaScript function IsNumeric. 
This function first determines the `ASCII` code of the keyboard key and then verifies that its `ASCII code` is within the range `48` to `57`.
Also it makes sure that the key pressed is not an special key like Backspace or Delete, if yes then that too is excluded.

**HTML Markup**

```
Numeric Value: <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" 
   ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" />
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Input digits (0 - 9)</span>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    function IsNumeric(e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNgbGb)

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this.

```
<input type="number" OnKeyPress="return myFunction()" />
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
    var e = event || window.event;  // get event object
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which; // get key cross-browser

    if (key < 48 || key > 57) { //if it is not a number ascii code
        //Prevent default action, which is inserting character
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); //normal browsers
            e.returnValue = false; //IE
    }
}
```